# Table Alignment and Width Issues

Tags: width, multirow

So I have this code:

```latex
\begin{center}
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{| c | c  c  c |}
      \hline
      \multirow{3}{*}{Equipment acquired at start of year} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Replacement cost (\$) for given years}\\
      \cline{2-4}
      & 1 & 2 & 3\\
      \hline
      1 & 4000 & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{5400} & 9800\\
      2 & 4300 & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{6200} & 8700\\
      3 & 4800 & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{7100} & -\\
      4 & 4900 & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{-} & -\\
      \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Which produces this table:

[image: Which produces this table:]

What I want is that the column 3 is evenly width like column under 1 and 2. Also I want "Equipment acquired at start of year" to be centered between the two multirows.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Here are two options, both of which use [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) for the construction of the `tabular`. `booktabs` suggests to avoid using vertical rules, since the columnar structure of a `tabular` necessarily lends itself to a horizontal alignment of elements within columns with visual separation provided by the *whitespace* between columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makecell,booktabs,array}

\begin{document}

% This construction does not require the array package
\begin{tabular}{ *{4}{c} }
  \toprule
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\makecell[c]{Replacement cost \\ for given years (\$)}} \\
  \cmidrule{2-4}
  \smash{\makecell[cb]{Equipment acquired \\ at start of year}} & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
  \midrule
  1 & 4000 & 5400 & 9800 \\
  2 & 4300 & 6200 & 8700 \\
  3 & 4800 & 7100 &  --  \\
  4 & 4900 &  --  &  --  \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

% This construction requires the array package
\begin{tabular}{ c *{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}} }
  \toprule
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\makecell[c]{Replacement cost \\ for given years (\$)}} \\
  \cmidrule{2-4}
  \smash{\makecell[cb]{Equipment acquired \\ at start of year}} & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
  \midrule
  1 & 4000 & 5400 & 9800 \\
  2 & 4300 & 6200 & 8700 \\
  3 & 4800 & 7100 &  --  \\
  4 & 4900 &  --  &  --  \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

In the first option, the header for columns 2-4 is stacked to naturally fit within the resulting width. In the second option, a fixed column width of `1cm` is specified for columns 2-4. You can adjust this width as needed, depending on how much you want to stretch out these columns.